# wx.python bind event to editableListBox list item's

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

Im looking for a way to bind a function to an event triggered from the selection of a list item inside the wx.gizmos editableListBox. I want the selection to populate the richTextCtrl1 with a string that can be edited by the user.

Below is a quick mock up of the UI design without event bindings or functions for clarity as my actual application is much larger.

```
import wx
import wx.richtext
import wx.gizmos

def create(parent):
        return myFrame(parent)

[wxID_MYFRAME, wxID_MYFRAMEMYEITABLELISTBOX, wxID_MYFRAMEMYFRAME_PANEL, 
 wxID_MYFRAMERICHTEXTCTRL1, 
] = [wx.NewId() for _init_ctrls in range(4)]

class myFrame(wx.Frame):
    def _init_ctrls(self, prnt):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, id=wxID_MYFRAME, name=u'myFrame', parent=prnt,
          pos=wx.Point(551, 188), size=wx.Size(500, 500),
          style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, title=u'myPanel')
        self.SetClientSize(wx.Size(498, 466))
        self.SetInitialSize(wx.Size(500, 500))

        self.myFrame_panel = wx.Panel(id=wxID_MYFRAMEMYFRAME_PANEL,
              name=u'myFrame_panel', parent=self, pos=wx.Point(0, 0),
              size=wx.Size(498, 466), style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)

        self.myEitableListBox = wx.gizmos.EditableListBox(id=wxID_MYFRAMEMYEITABLELISTBOX,
              label=u'myEitableListBox', name=u'myEitableListBox',
              parent=self.myFrame_panel, pos=wx.Point(8, 56), size=wx.Size(200,
          248))
        self.myEitableListBox.SetStrings(['this', 'that', 'other'])

        self.richTextCtrl1 =    wx.richtext.RichTextCtrl(id=wxID_MYFRAMERICHTEXTCTRL1,
              parent=self.myFrame_panel, pos=wx.Point(224, 64),
              size=wx.Size(248, 240), style=wx.richtext.RE_MULTILINE,
              value=u'')
        self.richTextCtrl1.SetLabel(u'')

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self._init_ctrls(parent)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = create(None)
    frame.Show()

    app.MainLoop()
```

I couldn't find a solution looking at the wx.python demo examples. Google hasn't helped much either. I have tried Boa Constructor and bound some events to the editable list box. Here are the bindings I have tried although none have worked:

```
self.myEitableListBox.Bind(wx.EVT_SYS_COLOUR_CHANGED,
          self.OnmyEitableListBoxSysColourChanged)
self.myEitableListBox.Bind(wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS, self.OnmyEitableListBoxSetFocus)
self.myEitableListBox.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnmyEitableListBoxLeftDown)

def OnmyEitableListBoxSysColourChanged(self, event):
    print self.myEitableListBox.GetSelection()
    print "fired"
    event.Skip()

def OnmyEitableListBoxSetFocus(self, event):
    print self.myEitableListBox.GetSelection(self)
    print "fired"
    event.Skip()

def OnmyEitableListBoxLeftDown(self, event):
    print self.myEitableListBox.GetSelection()
    lb = event.GetEventObject()
    data = lb.GetClientData(lb.GetSelection())
    print "fired", data
    event.Skip()
```

I have been reading the docs and trying to find tuts for wx.python. Nothing I have found yet has helped me understand how I can get the selected list item. If I could get the selected list item I think I could make the function that populates the ritchTextFeild. I should not that the GetSelection()'s and things are me trying and failing to understand what is going on. Also there are no errors generated in the console when run so I really dont know where to go from here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EditableListBox actually contains a ListCtrl, to gain access to the control use *self.myEitableListBox.ListCtrl*, by using the returned object you can Bind events.

The following example of your code with a few lines added will on selecting an item in the EditableListBox, add it to the richtext control.

```
import wx
import wx.richtext
import wx.gizmos

def create(parent):
        return myFrame(parent)

[wxID_MYFRAME, wxID_MYFRAMEMYEITABLELISTBOX, wxID_MYFRAMEMYFRAME_PANEL, 
 wxID_MYFRAMERICHTEXTCTRL1, 
] = [wx.NewId() for _init_ctrls in range(4)]

class myFrame(wx.Frame):
    def _init_ctrls(self, prnt):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, id=wxID_MYFRAME, name=u'myFrame', parent=prnt,
          pos=wx.Point(551, 188), size=wx.Size(500, 500),
          style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, title=u'myPanel')
        self.SetClientSize(wx.Size(498, 466))
        self.SetInitialSize(wx.Size(500, 500))

        self.myFrame_panel = wx.Panel(id=wxID_MYFRAMEMYFRAME_PANEL,
              name=u'myFrame_panel', parent=self, pos=wx.Point(0, 0),
              size=wx.Size(498, 466), style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)

        self.myEitableListBox = wx.gizmos.EditableListBox(id=wxID_MYFRAMEMYEITABLELISTBOX,
              label=u'myEitableListBox', name=u'myEitableListBox',
              parent=self.myFrame_panel, pos=wx.Point(8, 56), size=wx.Size(200,
          248))
        self.myEitableListBox.SetStrings(['this', 'that', 'other'])

        self.richTextCtrl1 =    wx.richtext.RichTextCtrl(id=wxID_MYFRAMERICHTEXTCTRL1,
              parent=self.myFrame_panel, pos=wx.Point(224, 64),
              size=wx.Size(248, 240), style=wx.richtext.RE_MULTILINE,
              value=u'')
        self.richTextCtrl1.SetLabel(u'')

        self.myEitableListBox.ListCtrl.Bind(
            wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED, self.on_listbox)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self._init_ctrls(parent)

    def on_listbox(self, event):
        text = '{}\n'.format(event.Text)
        self.richTextCtrl1.AppendText(text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = create(None)
    frame.Show()

    app.MainLoop()
```

There was an error because the depreciated PySimpleApp was used, use App instead which i have also changed in the above code.

Comment: you receive the event.Text from wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED,
i need to find the event attributes for more events like EVT_LIST_INSERT_ITEM (etc...), where can I find the documentation for other event.[attributes]? Ive tried event.GetItemText and many other methods and events(wx.EVT's) from the documentation hoping through trial and error something would work which is no way to program. I guess Im looking for documentation that has code examples to understand the documentation of wxPython. Or at least what event.attr are available for each wx.EVT?